# Man in the middle attack

Tags: man-in-the-middle, network-security

Does anyone know if there is a library that compiles on windows that would allow me to simulate a man in the middle attack? I am trying to learn network security and how to avoid such attacks, first I want to code something that will allow me to route any packet to my application, modify it and send it on its way. Presumably I need to handle timestamps and SSL certificates. I know there is a linux library called Ettercap that does just this but I need something that compiles easily for windows.

Comment: Just a suggestion to check out [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/home), it seems to have what you need and can be extended via scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for Cain and Able...It does all what ettercap does and runs on windows platforms